# Multiple ScriptControl instances sharing variable

Tags: asp.net, scope, scriptcontrol

I have a `ScriptControl` that uses an image as an embedded resource and `GetWebResourceUrl` to generate the `WebResource.axd` URL.  I am currently using `GetScriptDescriptors()` to send the URL to the JavaScript object.

The `ScriptControl` can be in a `Repeater`, so you may have 20+ instances.  They all use the same images (not customizable through property), so I would like to set the URL once in a variable and share it.  I know I could register a script block with a global variable, but would like to avoid that if possible.  Is there a way to set a variable within the scope of the control type (global -> **control type** -> control instance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work well:

```
        string imagesScript = String.Format(
            "MyNamespace.MyClass.prototype.imgDisabled = '{0}';" +
            "MyNamespace.MyClass.prototype.imgEnabled = '{1}';",
            Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(MyClass), "MyNamespace.disabled.png"),
            Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(MyClass), "MyNamespace.enabled.png")
        );

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(MyClass), "Images", imagesScript, true);
```

Then in my object I just do `this.imgDisabled` or `this.imgEnabled` to get the URLs.

**Edit:**  Another option is in `AssemblyInfo.cs` you set the JavaScript reference to `WebResource(..., PerformSubstitution = true)` then your .js file can have `<%= WebResource("MyNamespace.enabled.png") %>` anywhere you wish.  This can be where you actually use it or adding to the object prototype.

Comment: The first way allows the most flexibility (e.g. allowing custom image URLs with a property), so I'm using that.